# gevent fastcgi standalone not working?

Tags: python, cgi, fastcgi, gevent

As shown in this page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent-fastcgi, 
we can use gevent-fastcgi in stand-alone mode.

```
from gevent_fastcgi.server import FastCGIServer
from gevent_fastcgi.wsgi import WSGIRequestHandler

def wsgi_app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    yield 'Hello World!'


request_handler = WSGIRequestHandler(wsgi_app)
server = FastCGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 4000), request_handler, num_workers=4)
server.serve_forever()
```

However, when I tried it with wget, it get blocked.

```
$ wget http://127.0.0.1:4000/ping
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:4000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Python2.7.10, gevent-fastcgi==1.0.2.1, gevent==1.2.1

Is there anything wrong with the code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gevent-fastcgi` is a library to serve WSGI app via fastcgi protocol, but `wget` is trying to talk with HTTP, you need another server in front of "127.0.0.1:4000" to translate HTTP to fastcgi, like [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass).